# Why does the required attribute not work for input in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, input, required

I am a beginner so I am not aware of any conflicts that my code creates, but what I am trying to do is the following:

If the right option is selected from the dropdown, then an input field should appear and what I cannot seem to work out is to make input mandatory. I have tried adding the required attribute, but people could skip to the next part of the survey without filling in the input box. Adding the attribute class="obligatory" to the input does not help either because if another option is chosen, then the input does not show up and users cannot move on to the next part of the survey because the input field is hidden and obligatory at the same time.

I would be grateful for your help!

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p><font size="4">6. Mit welcher Sprache bist Du zuhause aufgewachsen?</font></p>
<select id="selectBox" onchange="changeFunc();">
 <option value ="Bitte">Bitte eine Option ausw&auml;hlen</option>
 <option value="Dialekt">Dialekt</option>
 <option value="Umgangssprache">Umgangssprache</option>
 <option value="Gepflegtes Hochdeutsch">Gepflegtes Hochdeutsch</option>
 <option value="Beides">Beides</option>
</select>

<input name="dd_number" placeholder="Bitte Dialekt angeben" required minlength="1" maxlength="40" class="form-control" type="text" style="display: none" id="textboxes">
 <script type="text/javascript">
  function changeFunc() {
   var selectBox = document.getElementById("selectBox");
   var selectedValue = selectBox.options[selectBox.selectedIndex].value;
    if ((selectedValue=="Dialekt")|(selectedValue=="Beides")){
     $('#textboxes').show();
    }
    else {
     $('#textboxes').hide();
    }
  }

</script>
```

Comment: Participants to the survey can skip filling in the input boxes... at least that is what happens to me

Answer (score 1):

You can add the `required` attribute with jQuery only when your `if` clause applies: (and remove it from the HTML code before)

Note: You should also use `removeAttr('reqired')` on the `else` clause since if at first the "Dialekt" option is chosen, the attribute is added, but remains there if the selection is changed afterwards. That way it will be removed again.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p><font size="4">6. Mit welcher Sprache bist Du zuhause aufgewachsen?</font></p>
<select id="selectBox" onchange="changeFunc();">
 <option value ="Bitte">Bitte eine Option ausw&auml;hlen</option>
 <option value="Dialekt">Dialekt</option>
 <option value="Umgangssprache">Umgangssprache</option>
 <option value="Gepflegtes Hochdeutsch">Gepflegtes Hochdeutsch</option>
 <option value="Beides">Beides</option>
</select>

<input name="dd_number" placeholder="Bitte Dialekt angeben" minlength="1" maxlength="40" class="form-control" type="text" style="display: none" id="textboxes">
 <script type="text/javascript">
  function changeFunc() {
   var selectBox = document.getElementById("selectBox");
   var selectedValue = selectBox.options[selectBox.selectedIndex].value;
    if ((selectedValue=="Dialekt")|(selectedValue=="Beides")){
     $('#textboxes').show().attr('required', '');
    }
    else {
     $('#textboxes').hide().removeAttr('required');
    }
  }

</script>
```

Comment: it still does not work, I really do not understand why. Now I get warning pop-ups for other input areas that worked fine before.

Comment: Do you have several inputs with the same ID? that would be invalid HTML...

Comment: I have checked and it does not seem to be the case...

Comment: What kind of warnings do you get?

Comment: I have added the full code below (perhaps this might help somehow) - I am getting warnings of radio inputs and other text inputs not being filled in even though they are and they worked just fine before. It is very weird. Thank you so much for helping me out!

Comment: sorry, I looked through your code, but I have no idea why these warnings would appear...

Comment: Thank you so much for all your effort!

Answer (score 1):

Since the form field already exists, you don't want to mess with attributes anymore, you are trying to change a "property" of the field.  To avoid confusion, jQuery now uses .prop() to make such changes.  Make sure to change it back to false when the user chooses another option!

See this fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/sv6phejL/

```
<html>
<body>
<form>
<p><font size="4">6. Mit welcher Sprache bist Du zuhause aufgewachsen?</font></p>
<select id="selectBox" onchange="changeFunc();">
 <option value ="Bitte">Bitte eine Option ausw&auml;hlen</option>
 <option value="Dialekt">Dialekt</option>
 <option value="Umgangssprache">Umgangssprache</option>
 <option value="Gepflegtes Hochdeutsch">Gepflegtes Hochdeutsch</option>
 <option value="Beides">Beides</option>
</select>

<input name="dd_number" placeholder="Bitte Dialekt angeben" minlength="1" maxlength="40" class="form-control" type="text" style="display: none" id="textboxes">
 <script type="text/javascript">
  function changeFunc() {
   var selectBox = document.getElementById("selectBox");
   var selectedValue = selectBox.options[selectBox.selectedIndex].value;
    if ((selectedValue=="Dialekt")|(selectedValue=="Beides")){
     $('#textboxes').show();
     $('#textboxes').prop('required', true);
    }
    else {
     $('#textboxes').hide();
     $('#textboxes').prop('required', false);
    }
  }
</script>
<br>
<input type="submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so, so much for your help! It did not work unfortunately. I tried to include it in the full code (it is posted above your code) and I could skip the input field without typing anything in it. It works perfectly in fiddle, not sure what is wrong

Comment: I think your "full code" posted below got cut off, or at least it appears that way.  If you can get the full code posted somewhere (with my changes incorporated from above as best you can), I can take another look.  P.S. Your issue might be related to the fact that your fields are not in the <form>...

Answer (score 0):

This is not the answer but the complete chunk of code. I tried implementing all suggestions but I think that I might be unaware of subtleties here...
I would be immensely grateful for your help. The issue now is that there are warning pop-up boxes for each quesiton, which was not the case before...

```
<div style="width: 40em;">
  <h2>
      Information
  </h2>
<p>
<font size="4">Bevor wir mit dem Experiment anfangen, brauchen wir noch einige Informationen von Dir. Alle personenbezogenen Angaben werden anonymisiert gespeichert und eine sp&auml;tere Zuordnung der angegebenen Daten zu Versuchspersonen wird den Forschenden nicht mehr m&ouml;glich sein.
  Wenn Du fertig bist, klicke bitte auf "Fortsetzen".</font>
</p>

<p><font size="4">1. Alter:</font><input name="Alter" type="text" size="30" class="obligatory"/>

<br>
<br>
<p><font size="4">2. Geschlecht</font>:<input name="Geschlecht" type="radio" value="male" class="obligatory" id="cgendermale" /><label for="cgendermale"><font size="4">M&auml;nnlich</font></label>
                   <input name="Geschlecht" type="radio" value="female" id="cgenderfemale"/><label for="cgenderfemale"><font size="4"> Weiblich</font></label>
                   <input name="Geschlecht" type="radio" value="divers" id="cgenderother"/><label for="cgenderother"> <font size="4">Divers</font></label>
 
<br>
<br>
<p><font size="4">3. Was ist Dein h&ouml;chster Bildungsabschluss?</font>:
  <select  name="Bildungsabschluss" required="true" id="Bildungsabschluss">
      <option value="kein Abschluss">kein Abschluss</option>
      <option value="Schulabschluss">Schulabschluss</option>
      <option value="Abitur oder gleichwertiger Abschluss">Abitur oder gleichwertiger Abschluss</option>
      <option value="Studium ohne Abschluss">Studium ohne Abschluss</option>
    <option value="Ausbildung">Ausbildung</option>
    <option value="Bachelor">Bachelor</option>
    <option value="Master">Master</option>
    <option value="Promotion">Promotion</option>
 </select>
  
<br>
<br>   
 <p><font size="4">4. Stelle Dir vor, die Leiter (s. unten) repräsentiert den relativen Sozialstatus der Menschen in Deutschland. An der Spitze der Leiter stehen Menschen mit relativ hohem Status – diejenigen, die das meiste Geld, die beste Bildung und die angesehensten Arbeitsplätze haben. Ganz unten sind Menschen mit relativ niedrigem Status – beispielsweise als arbeitslos Gemeldete. Relativ weit unten zu verorten wären auch diejenigen, die nur wenig Geld verdienen, einen niedrigen Bildungstand haben, und / oder Berufe ausüben, die die Gesellschaft als eher wenig respektabel ansieht.
  <br>
 <br>Wo würdest Du dich auf dieser Leiter einordnen? Wähle bitte die Sprosse, die Deinem empfundenen Sozialstatus am ehesten entspricht.
<br> </font></p>

<a href="https://ibb.co/7zkthfG"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/SxfwSjK/Leiter.jpg" alt="Leiter" border="0" width=220 height=300></a>
  
<p><font size="4">Deine Antwort</font>:
 <select  name="Socialstatus" required="true" id="Socialstatus">
      <option value="10">A</option>
      <option value="9">B</option>
      <option value="8">C</option>
      <option value="7">D</option>
    <option value="6">E</option>
      <option value="5">F</option>
        <option value="4">G</option>
        <option value="3">H</option>
        <option value="2">I</option>
        <option value="1">J</option>
      </select>  
<br>
<br>

<p><font size="4">5. Bist Du in Deutschland geboren?</font></p>
  <input name="Herkunft" type="radio" value="Ja" class="obligatory" id="Herkunft_Ja" /><label for="Herkunft_Ja"><font size="4">Ja</font></label>
                   <input name="Herkunft" type="radio" value="Nein" id="Herkunft_Nein"/><label for="Herkunft_Nein"><font size="4"> Nein</font></label>
                  
<br>
<br>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>  
<p><font size="4">6. Mit welcher Sprache bist Du zuhause aufgewachsen?</font></p>
<select id="selectBox" onchange="changeFunc();">
 <option value ="Bitte">Bitte eine Option ausw&auml;hlen</option>
 <option value="Dialekt">Dialekt</option>
 <option value="Umgangssprache">Umgangssprache</option>
 <option value="Gepflegtes Hochdeutsch">Gepflegtes Hochdeutsch</option>
 <option value="Beides">Beides</option>
</select>

<input name="dd_number" placeholder="Bitte Dialekt angeben" class="form-control" type="text" style="display: none" id="textboxes">
 <script type="text/javascript">
  function changeFunc() {
   var selectBox = document.getElementById("selectBox");
   var selectedValue = selectBox.options[selectBox.selectedIndex].value;
    if((selectedValue=="Dialekt")|(selectedValue=="Beides")){
     $('#textboxes').show().attr('required', '');
    }
    else {
     $('#textboxes').hide().removeAttr('required');
    }
  }

</script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p><font size="4">7. Welche Sprache sprichst Du aktuell hauptsächlich?</font></p>
<select id="selectB" onchange="changeFunction();">
<option value ="Bitte">Bitte eine Option ausw&auml;hlen</option>
<option value="Dialekt">Dialekt</option>
<option value="Umgangssprache">Umgangssprache</option>
<option value="Gepflegtes Hochdeutsch">Gepflegtes Hochdeutsch</option>
<option value="Beides">Beides</option>
</select>
<input name="d_number" placeholder="Bitte Dialekt angeben" class="form-control" type="text" style="display: none" id="textboxes2">
<script type="text/javascript">
function changeFunction() {
  var selectB = document.getElementById("selectB");
  var selectedVal = selectB.options[selectB.selectedIndex].value;
  if ((selectedVal=="Dialekt")|(selectedVal=="Beides")){
    $('#textboxes2').show().attr('required', '');
  }
  else {
    $('#textboxes2').hide().removeAttr('required');
  }
}
</script>



   
<p><font size="4">8. Wie gut (Skala von 0 - "gar nicht" bis 100 "ausgezeichnet") sprichst und verstehst Du:</font></p>
<form action="/action_page.php">
  <label for="Dialekt_skala"><font size="4">a. Dialekt:</font></label><br>
  <input type="text" id="Dialekt_skala" name="Skala" type="text" size="30" class="obligatory"/><br>
  <label for="Hochsprache_skala"><font size="4">b. Hochsprache:</font></label><br>
  <input type="text" id="Hochsprache_skala" name="Skala" type="text" size="30" class="obligatory"/><br><br>
```